# Condition for terms to lie in a geometric series

Tags: quadratics

$ax^2+2bx+c=0$ and $px^2+2qx+r=0$ has a common root. If terms $\frac ap, \frac bq, \frac cr$ lie on consecutive arithmetic series, Prove that terms p, q, r lie on consecutive geometric series.

**My Try**

Since they have a common root I derived the expression,

$$\frac{rb-cq}{qa-bp}=\frac{(ra-cp)^2}{4(bp-qa)^2}$$

How can I continue? any hint is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/628732/87880 I found a similar question here. But  my question is a bit different.

Answer (score 1):

Since the two polynomial have a common root, we can write $ax^2+2bx+c=a(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)=0$ and $px^2+2qx+r=p(x-\alpha)(x-\gamma)=0$. In the following, thanks to the hypotesis of arithmetic progression we will suppose $p,q,r,\gamma,\alpha\neq 0$. Also $a\neq 0$ to have a polynomial of degree $2$.

Thanks to the hypotesis we have the following informations (the first four equations are the Vieta's formula, and the last one is the arithmetic progression):
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\alpha\beta = \frac{c}{a}\\
\alpha+\beta = -\frac{2b}{a}\\
\alpha\gamma = \frac{r}{p}\\
\alpha + \gamma = -\frac{2q}{p}\\
\frac{b}{q}-\frac{a}{p} = \frac{c}{r} - \frac{b}{q}
\end{cases}
\quad\longrightarrow \quad
\begin{cases}
c = a\alpha\beta\\
b = -\frac{a(\alpha+\beta)}{2}\\
r = p\alpha \gamma\\
q= - \frac{p(\alpha+\gamma)}{2}\\
\frac{a(\alpha+\beta)}{p(\alpha+\gamma)}- \frac{a}{p} = \frac{a\beta}{p\gamma}- \frac{a(\alpha+\beta)}{p(\alpha+\gamma)}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Now continue to compute the last equation: we can simplify the factor $\frac{a}{p}$ and:
\begin{gather}
\frac{\alpha+\beta}{\alpha+\gamma} - 1 = \frac{\beta}{\gamma} - \frac{\alpha+\beta}{\alpha+\gamma}\\
\frac{\gamma(\alpha+\beta)-\gamma(\alpha+\gamma)}{\gamma(\alpha+\gamma)} = \frac{\beta(\alpha+\gamma)-\gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\gamma(\alpha+\gamma)}\\
\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma-\alpha\gamma-\gamma^2 = \alpha\beta+\beta\gamma-\alpha\gamma-\beta\gamma\\
\gamma^2-\alpha\gamma-\beta\gamma+\alpha\beta =0\\
(\gamma-\alpha)(\gamma-\beta)=0
\end{gather}
So we have only two possible cases: $\gamma=\alpha$ or $\gamma=\beta$.

Now $p,q,r$ are in geometric series if and only if
$$
\frac{p}{q}=\frac{q}{r} \ \Longleftrightarrow \ q^2 = pr
$$
and sobstituting $r$ and $q$ (as they appear in the system above) we obtain:
\begin{gather}
q^2 = pr\\
p^2\frac{(\alpha+\gamma)^2}{4} = p^2\alpha\gamma\\
(\alpha+\gamma)^2 = 4\alpha\gamma\\
(\gamma-\alpha)^2 = 0
\end{gather}
So if we require that the two starting polynomial have **exactly** one root in common (or $\alpha=\gamma=\beta$), we have the statement because the condition of arithmetic progression forces to $\gamma=\alpha$.

If not, it's possible that $\gamma=\beta$ and in this case $p,q,r$ are not in geometric progression (in general). Take for example $\beta=\gamma=1$, $\alpha=2$, $a=p=1$.