# If $a, b, c$ are in GP, then the equations $ax^2+2bx+c=0$ and $dx^2+2ex+f=0$ have a common root if $\frac{d}{a}, \frac{e}{b}, \frac{f}{c}$ are in...

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, functions, quadratics

> If $a, b, c$ are in GP, then the equations $ax^2+2bx+c=0$ and  $dx^2+2ex+f=0$ have a common root if $\frac{d}{a}, \frac{e}{b}, \frac{f}{c}$ are in...

From the question, we know $b^2=ac \implies b=\sqrt{ac}$
$$ax^2+2\sqrt{ac}x+c= (\sqrt{a}x + \sqrt{c})^2=0$$
$$\therefore x=-\sqrt{\frac{c}{a}}$$

But from here, I do not know how to proceed. Please help.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3892161/one-root-common-to-ax22bxc-0-and-dx22exf-0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [One root common to $ax^2+2bx+c=0$ and $dx^2+2ex+f=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3892161/one-root-common-to-ax22bxc-0-and-dx22exf-0)