# Condition for two quadratic equation to have one common root (Simplification)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, quadratic-forms, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-series

If a,b,c are in Geometric Progression, then the equations $ax^2+2bx+c=0$ and $dx2+2ex+f=0$ have a common root if $\frac da, \frac eb, \frac fc$ are in:

1. Arithmetic Progression
2. Geometric Progression
3. Harmonic Progression

Since this question was asked [already](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628732/condition-for-a-common-root-in-two-given-quadratic-equations) and many simple approach has been mentioned in the answers but I wanted to solve this question through common root condition only. So I tried the condition for one common root between two quadratic equation

$(a_1b_2−b_1a_2)(b_1c_2−c_1b_2)=(c_1a_2−a_1c_2)^2$

substituting the coefficient:

$(2ae−2bd)(2bf-2ce) = (cd−af)^2$      ........(I)

and also also substituted the value of b and c with $ar$ and $ar^2$ respectively as mentioned in the [answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628732/condition-for-a-common-root-in-two-given-quadratic-equations) but I couldn't simplify eqn (I) to

$\frac da + \frac fc = \frac {2e}{b}$. which would help in proving that they are in A.P.

Can anybody help me with the simplification of the equation?

**Edit1:**

Solution after suggestion from Blue:

$(2ae−2bd)(2bf-2ce) = (cd−af)^2$

$u \to d/a $

$v \to e/b $

$w \to c/f $

$(2ae−2bd)(2bf-2ce) = (cd−af)^2$

$(2abv−2bau)(2bcw-2bcv) = (acu−acw)^2$

$4ab.bc.(v−u)(w-v) = (ac)^2(u−w)^2$

$4ab^2c(v−u)(w-v) = (ac)^2(u−w)^2$

$4b^2(v−u)(w-v) = ac(u−w)^2$

as $abc$ are in G.P

$b^2 \to ac $

$4b^2(v−u)(w-v) = b^2(u−w)^2$

$4(v−u)(w-v) = (u−w)^2$

$4vw−4v^2-4uw+4uv = u^2+w^2-2uw$

$ u^2+w^2+(2v)^2+2uw-4vw-4uv=0$

$ (u+w-2v)^2=0$

$ u+w-2v=0$

$ u+w=2v$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... What did you get after substituting $b\to a r$ and $c\to a r^2$? I get something that factors nicely.

Comment: I not able figure out how to proceed after this 4r(e - rd) / (r^2d-f) = (r^2d - f) / ( f - re)

Comment: Clear the fractions, move everything to one side, and factor. (BTW: Your equation for the target terms being in A.P. should have $2e/b$ (not $2e/d$) on the right-hand side.) It could help to define $u:=d/a$, $v:=e/b$, $w:=f/c$, so that you can substitute $d\to ua$, $e\to vb$, $f\to wc$. It'll be easier to show $u+w=2v$.

Comment: Please review my answer which i posted as **Edit1**  in the the question. Please do share if you have a different approach.

Comment: Your solution is what I had in mind. Congratulations!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint